# Partial fraction decomposition proof

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials, solution-verification

In the Wikipedia page for partial fraction decomposition there is a formula given ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure)):

[image]

I am trying to use this to find the partial fractions of $\frac{1}{Q(x)}$ however I don't know if there are limitations on what $Q(x)$ is other than it being a polynomial. I thought that question would be answered if I read the proof for the formula but I wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

For partial fractions, you need to fully factor the denominator polynomial $Q(x)$ into linear or quadratic factors, for real functions without getting into complex roots.  That is a requirement for the method to be helpful.

Once you have quadratic factors, you can complete the square on them, and then your original rational function will separate into terms that can be integrated using either $\ln$, (for linear terms), $u$ substitution (for $\frac{kx}{x^2 + c^2}$), or using $\tan^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, this formula holds if and only if $Q$ has all distinct linear factors. Note that the Wikipedia article says that quite explicitly a few lines up.